# SIGSEGV when rewriting enums

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting SIGSEGV inside assignment operator, exactly when rewriting enums.
My struct:

```
struct Pawn
{
private:
    Q_GADGET
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(Position position MEMBER m_position)
    Q_PROPERTY(PawnType pawnType MEMBER m_pawnType)
    Pawn() :  m_position(Position::NotDefined), m_pawnType(PawnType::None) {}
    Pawn(const Pawn &a_other)
    {
        this->m_pawnType = a_other.m_pawnType;
        this->m_position = a_other.m_position;
    }
    Pawn &operator=(const Pawn &a_other)
    {
        this->m_pawnType = a_other.m_pawnType;
        this->m_position = a_other.m_position;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Pawn(){}

    enum Position
    {
        NotDefined = 0,
        Bottom,
        Left,
        Top,
        Right

    };

    enum PawnType
    {
        None = 0,
        Circle,
        Square,
        Diamond,
        Triangle,
    };

    Q_ENUMS(Position)
    Q_ENUMS(PawnType)

    Position m_position;
    PawnType m_pawnType;

};



typedef Pawn::PawnType PawnType;
typedef Pawn::Position Position;

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pawn)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pawn::Position)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pawn::PawnType)
```

Lines that causes error:

```
m_board[a_pawnPosition.y()][a_pawnPosition.x()] = m_board[current.y()][current.x()];
m_board[current.y()][current.x()] = Pawn();
```

Definiton of `m_board`:

```
Pawn m_board[10][10];
```

`a_pawnPosition` and `current` are in bounds

It doesn't always happen. I suppose that Q_PROPERTY may causing it, but i need them to read values from QML and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Getting a stack trace would be a good start.

Comment: What value is `current.y()` and `a_pawnPosition.y()` when it happens? Maybe you want to insert an assert before returning the value of those methods. (Or did you mean this when you say it's in bounds)

Comment: Please post MCVE, a main program  where `a_pawnPosition` and `current` and declared and inited + code leading to the crash...

Comment: "It doesn't always happen", probably UB. Are `a_pawnPosition` and `current` correctly initialized?

Comment: _a_pawnPosition and current are in bounds_ what are valid bounds?

Comment: @manni66: [0,9] probably...

Comment: @jpo38 do you really think that I didn't know?

Comment: Probably some out of bounds access. change your raw array to vector of vectors or std::array and use at() instead of operator[] - it will throw as soon as incorrect index is detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right. `current` was out of bounds, because it was reference, not copied value and sometimes i was deleting it from `QList` few lines before. Thanks for your answers.